# Hello, I have two ssl certificate one is a chain certificate and the other is the server certificate how can i add them to NGINX sever conf file?

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration

I have two ssl certificate one is a chain certificate and the other is the server certificate how can i add them to NGINX sever conf file?

Comment: 1. Search in Google or a search engine of your choice. 2. Post error and what you've tried if it fails. Good luck!

Comment: The `ssl_certificate` directive reads a file containing both the certificate and the chain. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.